# What is wrong with my cherry tree?

Tags: diseases, cherries

This tree is about 8 years old but only gives a few cherries a year that's not even tasty. It has a lot of sap coming out of the joints. I cut one out and splited it. I notice a brown line going down the middle. Is the tree rotting from within? How can I have it?

[image: the knot is cut off]

[image: cut surface]

[image: parts were cut]

[image: splited knot]